# save pdo query result to variable and use it on other queries

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm new in php programming, please help me.

I've to make two postgres queries from two separate databases, but one of the fist queries condition based on the other query result:

1st query:

```
<?php
$result = "SELECT ...
WHERE ... ";
$query = $pgszlaConn->prepare($result);
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        $contractid=$row[0];
        echo "<tr><td>$contractid</td></tr>";
?>
```

/In this query I've multiple results./

2nd query:

```
<?php
$result = "SELECT ...
    WHERE contract.contract_id= :contract";
$query = $pgConn->prepare($result);
$query->bindparam(':contract', $contractid);
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td></tr>";
?>
```

My problem is that the 2nd query has only one result based on the 1st query multiple results.

I'm not sure is this a good solution or not but my programming skills not so advanced ;-)

Please help me if you can!

Thanks a lot!

D. Attila

Comment: Can you help us understand the problem? Your second database has multiple rows WHERE contract_id matches that one value, right? Or do you want the results in the second database for each of the values in the first database?

Comment: "contractid" is the unique key between the two databases. I've multiple contract_ids from the first database and I'm looking for each of the matching rows from the second. But with my solution the $contractid variable in the 2nd query contains only the last "contractid" from the first so it leads to only one result :-(

Comment: When code part 1 ends, there is one value for `$contractId`: the last value in the loop. That one value is used in the 2nd query. You need to use each `$contractId` of the first loop in your second code instead.

Comment: Thanks the advice. And how can I do that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a beginner. But maybe try some simpler things first if your aim to learn. Like putting a loop in a loop and if you can't make it work, show what you tried and what issues you have. If you are only looking for a solution, ask a programmer to write the code for you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -2):

If i understand what you mean.
You need to make the second query within the loop of the first query so that for each id of the first query available, the id will be passed to the second query to query the database of the second table.

### Not with my system would have shown you some of my code.

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    echo "<tr><td>$contractid</td></tr>";
## now you make the second query to the second table with the id of the first table
$result = "SELECT WHERE contract.contract_id= :contract";
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td></tr>";
    } ## end of second query loop
} ## end of first query loop
```

Something like this should work just get the idea and implement it for yourself

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've try this solution, but the result is totally the same: as i make the second query within the loop of the first query the first query's results decreased to one hit.